# Как сменнить версию python в ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Установлен python 3.8.2, как установить версию 3.6.2? Версия ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Поставьте так:

```
sudo apt install python3.6
```

Питон 3.8 это никак не затронет.

Comment: Невозможно найти пакет python3.6

Comment: @Ylanaish https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get